# How to rectify wordart in Powerpoint using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am working on PowerPoint 2007. I want to rectify the wordart using VBA. The rectifications may involve aligning, resizing,etc.

Please suggest me how can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1)
    .ScaleWidth 1.38, msoFalse, msoScaleFromBottomRight
    .TextEffect.Text = "Your Text Here again"
    .IncrementRotation -15#
End With
```

The above assumes that your Wordart is the only shape on slide 1.

For more, try recording a macro and looking at the resulting code.